# I can not install Oculus DK2 setup: Installation Error

Tags: installation, windows-installer, oculus, virtual-reality

I'm trying to install Oculus DK2, and that for the first time. My computer is fresh and I didn't have any prior installation of Oculus. But I keep getting this error message:

***Sorry, we encountered an error during installation. Please restart your computer and try running Oculus Setup again***

Does anybody know how I can fix it?

P.S. Same problem has been reported before, and they suggested removing Oculus folder inside Program Files. But there is no such folder there for me.

Also, I have MCoffee antivirus on which is mandated by the university. I can not turn it off.

Actually when I download the setup, there is no a single executable setup. It is an online installer which apparently downloads the setup files to a local folder. Here is how that local folder looks like. But there is no msi installer for setup here except the visual CPP installer ones! I'm confused!
[image]

Comment: Run the MSI from an elevated command prompt like this: msiexec.exe /i <path_to_msi> /l*vx <path_to_logfile>. This will generate a debug logfile in the specified location which you should attach here.

Comment: Actually there is no single one-time installer. When you download it, it is a small-sized online installer that downloads files locally first. And when I go to that download folder, there is not a specific msi installer. I've updated my question this the picture of that folder. Can you take a look?

Comment: I can't download the installer so it's hard to give you more tips. You could run the setup again and see if there's a logfile being created somewhere in your User Temp directory (Just type %temp% in explorer bar). Or you could try to run the setup with /? or /help from the command line, sometimes the setups will show you a dialog with command line options and how to create a logfile. Often times a setup.exe is just a wrapper for an .msi which you could try to extract with 7zip and run it afterwards with the log parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation error was due to McAfee Enterprise antivirus. We disabled it and installation was successful.